# Can I show the most active users on my SharePoint site?

Tags: web-part, site, homepage

I would like to add a new web part to my SP home site, showing the most active users on the site. Is it possible? And if so how?

Comment: You need to add more details. How do you define "active" users for your specific site(s)? Do you plan to develop something of your own? If so, what language would you use etc.

Comment: Is it SP on premise or SharePoint online ?

Comment: @yash.kamdar : SharePoint online.

Comment: @Christoffer : I mean users that added or edited files in the shared libraries. I have a 365 group and the site has a number of possible web-parts and so I wonder if I can create / add / edit some web-part to show the most active users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB webpart available and I don't think this kind of data is available within SharePoint which you can consume. Still I would suggest you to check SharePoint Audit log reports, popularity trends and see if you can get report from this data.

Read this link for different options available for sharepoint usage reports.

https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-check-sharepoint-usage-reports/

Comment: Was thinking I could create a flow on a list and get that to be summarized on the site home page.

Comment: Flow would help you to analyse data, then you need to store in list somewhere and then show it on home page..actual challenge would be how will you find most active user..so first check this audit log data and see anyway you can derive this indicator